# Run jQuery event only once after a condition matches

Tags: jquery, html

I am making online product site, I am trigging a scroll event, at starting only 12 elements will be shown but when 8th element is scrolled to top scroll event should run only once, but it is running every time when I scroll down, please help.
Here is my Code:

```
var navigation_offset_top = $('.prods-list li:nth-child(4)').offset().top;  
    $(window).on("scroll",function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // current vertical position from the top
        // if scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) 
        { 
            console.log("Hi");
        }       
    });
```

Comment: Just remove the event handler.

Comment: put a var trigger=true at start.
after the first click make it false,
based on it allow to scroll or not

Answer (score 6):

Use `on()` and `off()`, and unbind the event handler when the scrolling reaches the right point :

```
var navigation_offset_top = $('.prods-list li:nth-child(4)').offset().top;  

$(window).on("scroll", doScroll);

function doScroll() {
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { 
        console.log("Hi");
        $(window).off('scroll', doScroll);
    }
};
```

Comment: You have a ")" to much in the bottom. Nice answer.

Comment: @PeterHøjlundAndersen - Indeed, edited out, thanks !

Comment: Are we taking advantage of hoisting here, when we reference the doScroll function inside of its definition?

Answer (score 4):

Call [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to unbind the event from the object.

```
$(window).on("scroll",function(){
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // current vertical position from the top
    // if scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
    if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) 
    { 
        console.log("Hi");
    }       
    $(this).unbind("scroll");
});
```

Comment: your code is working fine, but I want to run the same event when next 8th element
code:
`var navigation_offset_top = $('.prods-list li:nth-child(4)').offset().top;  
var navigation_offset_top1 = $('.prods-list li:nth-child(8)').offset().top;
$(window).on("scroll",function(){
var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll_top > navigation_offset_top || scroll_top > navigation_offset_top1) 
{ 
console.log("Hi");
$(this).unbind('scroll');
}       
});`
but it is not working.. please check it once.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is **.one** method

```
$(window).one("scroll",function(){
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // current vertical position from the top
    // if scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
    if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) 
    { 
        console.log("Hi");
    }       
});
```

You can learn more here: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Some of the answers solve your problem? If not try putting your code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: `one()` only works once, so the second you touch the scrollbar or the mousewheel, it fires once, and no more, so it never gets to the conditional statement. Amazed this got two upvotes ?

Comment: This is getting upvoted probably because the title doesn't really match the question. `one()` is a proper way to run a jQuery event only once, which is what the question title asks.

Answer (score 1):

you can unbind the event after complete.

Like  `$(this).unbind("scroll);`

Answer (score -1):

```
var thisHash = window.location.hash;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    if(window.location.hash) {
      jQuery.fancybox(thisHash, {
        padding: 20
        // more API options
      });
    }

});
```

This is even better, because you don't need the button to trigger fancybox.
And with the previous code I wasn't able to insert a form inside fancybox, cause everytime I was clicking inside the form, it was relaunching fancybox.