# jQuery scroll not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my html page ther is one load-more class.`<p class="load-more">Load more</p>`. When user scroll down to this div i need to execute a function . For example i need to alert "Hi". For this i used the following code .

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var hT = $(".load-more").offset().top,
        hH = $(".load-more").outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
        alert("Hi");
    }
});
```

But here alert is working more than one time . Ie alert is repeating 4,5 times . Why this is happening ?
i see this answer [Run jQuery event only once after a condition matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637249/run-jquery-event-only-once-after-a-condition-matches) but it is not working .

Please see this js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4cfjq1tg/2/. Here when we scroll down to bottom , it is alerting hi more than one time .

```
Here what i need is
```

> how can i execute some function on certain condition ? for example when scroll down to load more then i need to check the css display
>   value of .load-more. If that load-more is display block alert **Hi** .
>   else don't do anything

**UPDATE**

I solve this issue using this solution

```
var in= 0;

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var hT = $(".load-more").offset().top,
        hH = $(".load-more").outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();
   if(in==0){
     if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
       if($(".load-modre").css("display")!=="block"){
             alert("hii");
             in ++;
            }
            }  } 

    });
```

All credits are going to [FFdeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7011883/ffdeveloper)  and [Farzin Kanzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1425882/farzin-kanzi) .

Thank you friends

Comment: Please give us some more details. Maybe your problem is in some other parts of your code because this piece, as is, works for me. JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4cfjq1tg/1/

Comment: no in this also problem .see this https://jsfiddle.net/4cfjq1tg/2/ . when you scroll down it is alerting hi more than one time

Comment: @FFdeveloper can you please write the answer so that i can accept  . i found this logic by your  js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4cfjq1tg/5/

Comment: @abilash er that logic doesn't work as it should. I found another post that seems to work, i answered with the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you scroll your page

```
 $(window).scroll(function()...
```

will fire multiple times. This is normal that you see multiple alerts.

**Update**:

It's better you do this:

```
var loaded = false;
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
     if(!loaded)
     {
         var hT = $(".load-more").offset().top,
             hH = $(".load-more").outerHeight(),
             wH = $(window).height(),
             wS = $(this).scrollTop();

         if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
             if($(".load-modre").css("display")!=="block"){
                 alert("hii");
                 loaded = true;
             }
         }
     }
});
```

It is also better in performance, because after `loaded` set to true, We have not any process in next scrolls.

Comment: then how can i execute some condition  ? for example when scroll down to load more then i need to check the css display value of .load-more. If that load-more is display block alert hi . else don't do anything /

Comment: Some conditions or css changes has not problem with repeat. They are different than alert that must show only one time. You can see many web pages that has scroll function to hide/show the top menu. For example top menu show on `scrollTop > 200` It repeats but not any problem. I will find some sample to you.

Comment: You can see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480694/hide-menu-on-scroll-down-then-show-the-menu-when-the-scroll-up-reach-0-javascri

Comment: My english is not good, But just now I found what you want. To load more it must fire only one time. So you can use a boolean, `if(this).scrollTop() > 200) myBoolean = true;` This set your boolean true when page reaches to a scroll value and you can use this to check if `load more` is needed or not. The boolean changes from `false` to `true` but never chages back to `false`.

Comment: Please see my update :)

Comment: Yes it's ok. but it was better to using a boolean to check condition, instead of a number ('in').

Comment: ok. then can you update the answer with code .

Answer (score 3):

Below code snippet to stop alerting more then one time on scroll

> You can also check the link [Auto Load More Data On Page Scroll
>   (jQuery/PHP)](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/auto-load-records-on-page-scroll)
>   and append results into the `div`

```js
var loading = true;

$(window).scroll(function() {

 var loadMoreTop  = $('.load-more').position().top,
  loadMoreHeight = $(".load-more").outerHeight(),
  windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
  windowHeight = $(window).height()
  windowPosition = windowScrollTop + windowHeight - loadMoreHeight;
  
 if (windowPosition >= loadMoreTop && loading) { 
  alert('Hi');
  loading = false;
 }
 
});
```

```css
.container {height: 100%;}
.load-more {background: #000; padding: 10px; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
 <ul id="results">
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
   <li>Hi</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="load-more">LOAD MORE...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All the solutions i've seen for this question in this post seems to not work properly.

Please see the accepted answer of this post:

[Trigger event when user scroll to specific element - with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery)

Seems to work quite good.

Hope this could be the real solution of this post.